# CommonNavigator View: Some Hotkeys don't work

Tags: eclipse-rcp, hotkeys

I have a RCP application that reuses "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator" to give us a project view. It works well, except for one thing: Some hotkeys (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Delete) just don't do anything, while others like F2 or F5 work just fine. I assume it might have to do with the fact that those keys that do not work also do something in the context of the editor(s).

I use Helios as the target plattform and work on windows XP.

Any ideas?

[alt text http://www.panschk.de/pe.jpg](http://www.panschk.de/pe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the problem was to register the corresponding Actions/Commands. When they are not registered, the Hotkeys will not work, because there is no registered command to point to.

So the solution was pretty stupid and simple:

ActionBarAdvisor:

```
protected void makeActions(final IWorkbenchWindow window) {
[...]
        copyAction =ActionFactory.COPY.create(window);
        register(copyAction);
        pasteAction = ActionFactory.PASTE.create(window);
        register(pasteAction);
        deleteAction = ActionFactory.DELETE.create(window);
        register(deleteAction);
}
```